# Use Cygwin in Visual Studio Code and login as a different user?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, cygwin

I am trying to setup the `Visual Studio Code` environment on my Windows machine and Now I need to use `Cygwin` as the shell in the intergrated shell. But I have some questions:

1. I am able to run a Cygwin shell in the intergrated shell by adding the following code in the user settings:

   ```
   // Cygwin Prompt
   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "PATH_TO_CYGWIN.EXE",    
   // Use this to keep bash from doing a `cd $HOME`    
   "terminal.integrated.env.windows": { "CHERE_INVOKING": "1" },
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [ "--login" ]
   ```

   But now I want to login as a different user when opening the shell because the Windows user I am logging on doesn't have administrative privilege. Outside of VS Code I can do it by modifying the `Cygwin.bat` file as `runas /user:MY_USER_NAME "bash --login -i"` and run this script. But if I change the user settings to 
   `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows":PATH_TO_MY_BAT_FILE`, it actually opens another widnow outside of VS Code. So can I archieve it within VS Code?
2. Also, I would like to be able to select which shell I want to execute. Because besides Cygwin, I sometimes need to run `cmd.exe` too. I have searched online and they all suggest using  `Terminal: select default shell`. But it looks to me that changing this (to cmd.exe for example) would modify my user settings directly and so my previous settings for Cygwin would be lost (I don't know if this is the right place, because I don't want to change the "default" behavior, I just want to have the freedom to select). And the choices of "default shell" are fixed to three items: command prompt, power shell and git bash. Can I add my Cygwin to thi list?